# Does every Android process have its own thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, process

Does every Android process by definition start its own thread? In particular, if I start a Service in a separate process **within the same app** by setting its `android:process` attribute in my manifest file, will it automatically run on a separate thread from the main thread of my app's default process?

I've read through the [Processes and Threads](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) Android documentation and this seems to be the implication, but it doesn't answer the question directly.

Comment: it will run is a separate process (different PID) - so the thread by definition has to be different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, since it is a different process, it will be a different thread.

> android:process
>
> The name of the process where the service is to run.
> Normally, all components of an application run in the default process
> created for the application. It has the same name as the application
> package. The  element's process attribute can set a
> different default for all components. But component can override the
> default with its own process attribute, allowing you to spread your
> application across multiple processes.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element

Thread run within a process

https://www.slashroot.in/difference-between-process-and-thread-linux

Comment: Thanks. I'm happy to officially accept your answer if you provide a link to some sort of documentation supporting it.